# Changing the active colors of the buttons in toolbar in sencha using SASS

Tags: sencha-touch, sass, compass-sass

I'm looking to change my button colors and active colors of buttons in toolbar in sencha.  After following some tutorial i got this.

My sample sass code:

```
@mixin sencha-toolbar-ui('toolbarcolour', #333333,'glossy') {
      $toolbar-border-color: darken(#333333, 50%);
      $toolbar-button-color: darken(#0088CC, 10%);

      .x-toolbar-#{toolbarcolours} {
        @include background-gradient(#333333, 'glossy');

        .x-toolbar-title {
          @include color-by-background(#FFFFFF);
          @include bevel-by-background(#FFFFFF);
        }

        .x-button, .x-field-select .x-input-text, .x-field-select:before {
          @include toolbar-button(#0088CC, 'glossy');
        }
      }
    }
```

When compile the code using Compass I'm getting the following error:

```
    error app.scss (Line 32: Invalid CSS after "...cha-toolbar-ui(": expected va
    riable (e.g. $foo), was "'toolbarcolour'...")
    Sass::SyntaxError on line ["32"] of D: Invalid CSS after "...cha-toolbar-ui(": e
    xpected variable (e.g. $foo), was "'toolbarcolour'..."
    Run with --trace to see the full backtrace.
```

Answer (score 0):

Arguments for mixins need to be named something, they can't just be a collection of values.  Here I've named the arguments and given them a default value:

```
@mixin sencha-toolbar-ui($class: toolbarcolour, $color: #333333, $style: glossy) {
    $toolbar-border-color: darken($color, 50%);
    $toolbar-button-color: darken(#0088CC, 10%);

    .x-toolbar-#{$class} {
        @include background-gradient($color, $style);

        .x-toolbar-title {
            @include color-by-background(#FFFFFF);
            @include bevel-by-background(#FFFFFF);
        }

        .x-button, .x-field-select .x-input-text, .x-field-select:before {
            @include toolbar-button(#0088CC, $style);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your response                                                                  Still getting the same syntax error              C:\Ruby193\bin>compass compile D:\My\WebDesign\xampp\htdocs\sencha\menu-mode-fin
al-build\resources\sass
    error app.scss (Line 32: Invalid CSS after "...cha-toolbar-ui(": expected va
riable (e.g. $foo), was "($ class toolba...")
Sass::SyntaxError on line ["32"] of D: Invalid CSS after "...cha-toolbar-ui(": e
xpected variable (e.g. $foo), was "($ class toolba..."
Run with --trace to see the full backtrace

Comment: The error indicates that there is a space between the `$` and `class`, it should be all together without a space:  `$class`.  Is the comment breaking the formatting of the error or is there really a space there?

Comment: I removed the space and tried still getting the error                           C:\Ruby193\bin>compass compile D:\My\WebDesign\xampp\htdocs\sencha\menu-mode-fin
al-build\resources\sass
    error app.scss (Line 32: Invalid CSS after "...cha-toolbar-ui(": expected va
riable (e.g. $foo), was "($class toolbar...")
Sass::SyntaxError on line ["32"] of D: Invalid CSS after "...cha-toolbar-ui(": e
xpected variable (e.g. $foo), was "($class toolbar..."
Run with --trace to see the full backtrace

Comment: You've removed the colon from your variable declaration as well:  `$variableName: value`.